# Restart node.js after crash in pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, command-line, pm2

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135371/can-the-pm2-node-module-restarts-the-app-after-crash-automatically), pm2 should restart crashed applications.

When my application crashes nothing happens and the process is missing from `pm2 list`. Do I have to somehow activate an 'auto restart option'?

I am using:

- pm2 v0.12.3
- node v0.11.14
- Amazon Linux

Comment: Usually, pm2 should always restart your app automatically on crashes. If it isn't I guess that is a problem that can't be fixed with only a restart. E.g. Can't connect to database. PM2 will tries to restart a number of times and after that will give up because db is offline. This is simple to debug, just watch the logs with "pm2 logs" and see what is generating this crash and fix it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had poor results trying to use PM2 as the sole means by which to monitor my Node.js applications.  In the end the approach I took was to use to [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor the application process and use `pm2` within the `monit` configuration script to `startOrRestart` or `stop` the process.  For example, in a `monitrc` file:

`check process node_app matching /home/webapps/node_app/app.js
   start program = "/bin/bash -lc 'cd /home/webapps/node_app && PM2_HOME=/home/webapps/.pm2 /usr/bin/pm2 startOrRestart processes.json'"
   stop program  = "/bin/bash -lc 'cd /home/webapps/node_app && PM2_HOME=/home/webapps/.pm2 /usr/bin/pm2 stop processes.json'"`

Not only does this allow you to "watch the watcher" it helps as a work-around for the persistent [PM2 fails to restart applications after a reboot bug](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues?&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+reboot).

Answer (score 0):

PM2 should automatically restart apps, but there are a few alternative ways to ensure PM2 will do this (including the `--watch` command you've already linked to). The route I've taken is:

```
$ pm2 startup systemd
```

PM2 will then output instructions to execute the following command *(note, I'd recommend copy/pasting the output from the above* `startup` *command rather than using my example below)*:

```
$ sudo su -c "env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup systemd -u USERNAME --hp /home/USERNAME"
```

This will create the environment variables to restart your processes if the app crashes or the server reboots.

Comment: `--watch` is not meant to restart upon crash ;) is rather "PM2 can automatically restart your application when a file is modified in the current directory or its subdirectories", check here http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/